# How to select directory on Smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I need to add chooser for directory as JFILECHOOSER on SMARTGWT.
Any suggestions please?
I have tried this but I must select the file.

```
FileItem = new FileItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheched the docs, for security reasons you can't specify a default path :(

https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#file-upload-state-typefile